# How to delete a record from a dictionary?

Tags: alfresco

I have an invalid dictionary in Alfresco database, I need to delete some records from that dictionary. How to do that programmatically? Manually? 
Thank you!
(this was custom dictionary which was filled up from the file programmatically, now it is one of Alfresco's nodes )

Comment: What do you mean by `dictionary` ? An entry in the data dictionary area of the Alfresco repo? Some custom properties? A site datalist? Something else?

Comment: some custom properties

Comment: An entry in the data dictionary area of the Alfresco repo

Comment: Just use the repo browser in share and delete the node then?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gagravarr that you can just delete the nodes you no longer want.

If you want to remove the content model from the data dictionary, you'll need to first delete all of the nodes that are instances of types that are in the model and remove any aspects defined in the model from existing nodes, then you can remove the content model from your system.

A good way to find nodes that are instances of a certain type is to use the node browser and the TYPE:"sc:someType" syntax. Similarly, you can use ASPECT:"sc:someAspect" to find nodes that have a certain aspect applied.

Hopefully, your custom content model was added and packaged in an AMP. If so, you just need to find the model XML file and delete it, then delete the reference from the model context file. Then, you can re-package the AMP and deploy it to your system.

In an Alfresco SDK project structure, the model is typically in a directory like some-project/some-project-platform-jar/src/main/resources/alfresco/module/some-project-platform-jar/model/content-model.xml.

The model context file is usually something like: some-project/some-project-platform-jar/src/main/resources/alfresco/module/some-project-platform-jar/context/bootstrap-context.xml.